# Image map incorporation

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

All I want do is I have a map of a country with different states, and describe the state in a separate page when user clicks on a that state. I created an image map with different states as areas, but I was not able to put actual coordinates of the state that was clicked.

Here is my code:

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
function point_it(event,id){
pos_x = event.offsetX?(event.offsetX):event.pageX-document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetLeft;
pos_y = event.offsetY?(event.offsetY):event.pageY-document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetTop;
k=pos_x;
document.getElementById(id).coords.value=k;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br><br>
<h1>Country Locations</h1>
<div id="pointer_div">
<img alt="country map " src="images/country.jpg"       


onclick="point_it(event,'state')"     width="500" height="300" usemap="#map" />

</div>
<map name="map">
<area  id="State" alt="IT" shape="default" coords=" " href="#bang" />
</map> 
<div id="bang"><h3>State</h3></div>
<p>Located at Country</p>
```

Comment: I think you'll need the coordinates in your imagemap for any of this to work.

Comment: Yes That I know ,but I want it dynamically as someone clicks on a particular part of image rather than put it inside under coords as hard coded

Comment: How will you relate the coordinates to the states?